# Get the posttype of a taxonomy/term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, breadcrumb

I'm coding a breadcrumb and I want to return the CPT name in front of the first taxonomy term.

My website's structure is like the following:

```
- CPT name
  - Taxonomy Term
    - Taxonomy Child Term
      - Post Archive of the articles from the CPT and the two terms
```

If the user is in the Archive, the Breadcrumb should say:

```
Home > CPT name > Parent Term > Child Term
```

I'm currently able to return the parent and child terms, but how do I return the post type name? I have on custom taxonomy for each custom post type, so if would be cool if I could get the post type by a function like this:

```
global $wp_query;
$term_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$thisTerm = $term_obj->term_id;
$thisTerm = get_term( $thisTerm );
$postType = get_category($thisTerm->posttype);
```

I know that the term object does not have a `posttype`-key, but I could get the taxonomy like this. Is there a possibility to get the post type by entering the taxonomy which is registered to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881712/800452) user [indextwo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/988246/indextwo) suggests to do the following:

Use the [`get_taxonomy( $taxonomy-slug )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_taxonomy/) function which returns an object that contains all the associated post types. As suggested in the comments, we can then use 
[`get_post_type_object( $post-type-slug )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object) to get the object and Singular Label.

```
$post_type_names    = array(); // Array( 'post-type-slug' => 'Post Type Label' );
$taxonomy           = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );

if( ! empty( $taxonomy ) ) {
    $tax_object = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );
    $cpt_array  = $tax_object->object_type;

    if( ! empty( $cpt_array ) ) {
        $post_type_names = array_flip( $cpt_array );

        foreach( $post_type_names as $cpt_slug => $tmp ) {
            $post_type_names[ $cpt_slug ] = get_post_type_object( $cpt_slug )->labels->singular_name;
        }
    }
}
```

The above will return the post type slugs in a generic Array.

```
Array(
    [post-type-slug]  => 'Post Type Name',
    [post-type-slug2] => 'Post Type Name 2',
)
```

Comment: I changed it tho this, it now returns the label: `if( ! empty( $taxonomy ) ) {
        $tax_object = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );
        $cpt_array  = $tax_object->object_type;
        $posttype_obj = get_post_type_object($cpt_array[0]);
        $posttype = $posttype_obj->label;
      }`